# Plot made of array from a pandas dataset in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

The problem is: I have a SQLAlchemy database called NumFav with arrays of favourite numbers of some people, which uses such a structure:

```
id      name       numbers
 0 Vladislav     [2, 3, 5]
 1   Michael  [4, 6, 7, 9]
```

`numbers` is postgresql.ARRAY(Integer)

I want to make a plot which demonstrates `id` of people on X and `numbers` dots on Y in order to show which numbers have been chosen like this:

[image: reference figure]

I extract data using

```
df = pd.read_sql(Session.query(NumFav).statement, engine)
```

How can I create a plot with such data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [**`explode`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the number lists into "long form":

```py
df = df.explode('numbers')
df['color'] = df.id.map({0: 'red', 1: 'blue'})

# id  name       numbers  color
# 0   Vladislav  2        red
# 0   Vladislav  3        red
# 0   Vladislav  5        red
# 1   Michael    4        blue
# 1   Michael    6        blue
# 1   Michael    7        blue
# 1   Michael    9        blue
```

Then you can directly [**`plot.scatter`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html):

```py
df.plot.scatter(x='name', y='numbers', c='color')
```

[image: numbers vs name scatter plot]

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    plt.plot(row['numbers'])
plt.legend(df['name'])
plt.show()
```

[image]